# How do I access the value from a dictionary in a list in a dictionary?

Tags: json, list, dictionary, python-3.7

for example this is the data:

data = {'number': 3, 'message': 'success', 'people': [{'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Chris Cassidy'}, {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Anatoly Ivanishin'}, {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Ivan Vagner'}]}

how do I print only the names of the people in this case?

required output:

('Chris Cassidy', 'Anatoly Ivanishin', 'Ivan Vagner')

I can't wrap my head around this, please help. :)

Comment: is this a question regarding `javascript` or `python3` ? Did you try any code ?

Comment: It is regarding Pythhon-3.7. I did try solving it on my own but couldn't. I could access the values from a dictionary in a list, but the extra-added dictionary in the start made all the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
names = []
for person in data["people"]:
    names.append(person["name"])
```

`names` will then have your desired list.